# AngularJS, how use variables in an external JS <script> in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am not an AngularJS expert, and I have the simple question in subject.

My code defined an app and controller in a  at the begin of the page:

```
 <script>
    var isisApp = angular.module('isisApp', []);
    isisApp.controller('AccountListCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.sample = {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'age': 25, 'AccountType': 'Safekeeping',
            'address': {'street': 'Dorsstok', 'city': 'Erica'},
            'phone': [{'type': 'home', 'number': '+31591302900'}, {'type': 'mobile', 'number': '+31625299740'}, {'type': 'Business', 'number': '+43223627551'}],
            'account': [{'type': 'Bonds', 'value': '111111'}, {'type': 'Stocks', 'value': '$ 0625299740'}, {'type': 'Funds', 'value': '999990'}],
            'json_read_date': '4/12'
    };
 });
 </script>
```

For instance I would json_read_date in an external  where I build my chart (ChartJS), how read a variable there? I got a sample like this one but it is not working:

```
var read_date= $('[ng-controller="AccountListCtrl"]').scope().json_read_date;
```

I get this error: 'undefined' is not a function etc.

Do you have any idea? I am using ng-controller="AccountListCtrl" inside the body tag, where also my second script is..

Thanks in advance!
Fabio

After Isha's answer I adapted my code, but I cannot see any Chart:

```
<!-- Graph !-->
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="450"></canvas>
<script>
         isisApp.controller('ChartJS', function($scope, Init) {
                 $scope.init = Init;

                 var delivery = $scope.init.json_doughnut_delivery;
                 var taxother = $scope.init.json_doughnut_taxother;
                 var supply = $scope.init.json_doughnut_supply;

                            var doughnutData = [
                                {
                                    value: delivery,
                                    color: "#000000"
                                },
                                {
                                    value: taxother,
                                    color: "#838383"
                                },
                                {
                                    value: supply,
                                    color: "#FFFF00"
                                }
                            ];

                            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
                        });
</script>
```

before it was working simply with:

```
 <!-- Graph !-->
 <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="450"></canvas>
 <script>
 var doughnutData = [
    {
        value: 32,
        color: "#000000"
    },
    {
        value: 23,
        color: "#838383"
    },
    {
        value: 11,
        color: "#FFFF00"
    }
 ];

 var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `factory` to provide the `sample` data and inject it in other controllers, directives, ...

```
isisApp.factory('Sample', function(){

 return {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Smith', 'age': 25, 'AccountType': 'Safekeeping',
            'address': {'street': 'Dorsstok', 'city': 'Erica'},
            'phone': [{'type': 'home', 'number': '+31591302900'}, {'type': 'mobile', 'number': '+31625299740'}, {'type': 'Business', 'number': '+43223627551'}],
            'account': [{'type': 'Bonds', 'value': '111111'}, {'type': 'Stocks', 'value': '$ 0625299740'}, {'type': 'Funds', 'value': '999990'}],
            'json_read_date': '4/12'
    };

});

isisApp.controller('AccountListCtrl', function($scope, Sample){
$scope.sample = Sample;
//now you have an access 'json_read_date' inside this controller, via  - Sample.json_read_date OR $scope.sample.json_read_date
});

isisApp.controller('ChartJS', function($scope, Sample){
$scope.sample = Sample;
//now you have an access 'json_read_date' inside this controller, via  - Sample.json_read_date OR $scope.sample.json_read_date

});
```

Hope It helps.

Comment: Hi Isha, thanks a lot for your help. I went ahead but I didn't succeed in creating the Chart: the code in my answer below doesn't work..